# Output issue regarding a number already being "contained" in another

Tags: bash, shell-script

So this is the script I have, **add_nurses.sh**:

```
#!/bin/bash

sed -i '/^$/d' nurses.txt

if [ $# != 4 ] ; then
    echo "Error: Syntax: $0 <id number>:<name>:<associated Health Center>:<number of vaccines done>:<availabiliy>"
else

a=$(awk -F "[:]" '{print $3}' nurses.txt | grep -c "$3")
b=$(awk -F "[:]" '{print $1}' nurses.txt | grep -c "$2")

if [[ "$a" -gt "0" ]] ; then
    echo "Error: The Health Center introduced already has a nurse in it."

    elif [[ "$b" -gt "0" ]] ; then
        echo "Error: There is already a nurse registered with that id."

    else
    
    echo "$2:$1:$3:0:$4" >> nurses.txt
    echo "Nurse added."
    fi
fi
```

I want this script to add , lets say nurse X to nurses.txt. BUT if there is already a nurse registered in the same location as X OR if the id that X has is  already taken by another nurse on the nurses.txt, i don´t want to add nurse X to the list.

My **nurses.txt** content is as follows:

```
12345:Ana Correia:CSLisboa:0:0
98765:Joao Vieira:CSPorto:0:1
```

If I run the program like this:

```
./add_nurses.sh "João Vieira" 98765 "CSPorto" 0
```

I get the correct message for those arguments which is:

```
Error: The Health Center introduced already has a nurse in it.
```

If I change the location to a string that has the same number of letters, but is different than `CSPorto`, for example:

```
./add_nurses.sh "João Vieira" 98765 "CSPorta" 0
```

I also get the right output, which is:

```
Error: There is already a nurse registered with that id.
```

**BUT** if I input it like this:

```
./add_nurses.sh "João Vieira" 9876 "CSPorta" 0
```

It gives me the wrong output, which is:

```
Error: There is already a nurse registered with that id.
```

The id´s `98765` and `9876` are different, so why am I getting this output and how can I solve this?

**ALSO**, if I input a Health Center with less characters as in:

```
./adiciona_enfermeiros.sh "João Vieira" 98765 "CSPort" 0
```

I get:

```
Error: The Health Center introduced already has a nurse in it.
```

But I want the script to assume `CSPort` isn´t the same location as `CSPorto` or `CSPorta`
Need help solving this two issues! Thanks a lot in advance :)

Comment: What happens when you grep for part of a word in a file?

Comment: @KevinO in this case, you get the number of times that the location given by the user appears in nurses.txt (variable a) and the same thing for the id (variable b)

Comment: Grep for 1 in /etc/passed. Do you only get a single result? The point is your grep is not an exact match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the problem is that `grep 9876` sees that `9876` is present, but you want to see it only if the number is there as a word. If you use the `-w` switch when looking for the ID number, you should get the response you're looking for. For the same reason, it sees `CSport` as present in either `CSporto` or `CSporta`. The `-w` switch to grep should resolve that as well.

```
a=$(awk -F "[:]" '{print $3}' nurses.txt | grep -cw "$3")
```

Comment: Since you're already using awk, why not use that to check for the desired string? `a=$(awk -F ":" -v string=$3 '$3==string' nurses.txt)` that would ensure you only find it where it is relevant, in the third field.

Answer (score 2):

As already mentioned, the problem is that your approach will also find substrings. However, the whole thing is quite fragile and inefficient since you are reading the file multiple times and use `grep` which can find a match anywhere on the line. I would instead do the entire processing in a single `awk` call. Something like this:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

if [ $# != 4 ] ; then
    echo "Error: Syntax: $0 <id number> <name> <associated Health Center> <number of vaccines done> <availabiliy>"
    exit 1
fi

## Have awk print out 'var=value' pairs and 'source' them
## into your current shell so they will be available as
## variables in the current script.
. <(awk -v id="$2" -v center="$3" -F':' \
        '{
           if($1==id){i=1}
           if($3==center){c=1}
         } END{ print "idExists="i,"centerHasNurse="c}' nurses.txt)


## I am separating the two tests since they are not mutually exclusive
## this way, you will get separate messages when the id exists and when
## the nurse exists. Either error will cause the script to fail, but this
## way you will know if the id exists and the center has a nurse.
foundError=""
if [[ -n $idExists ]]; then
  echo "Error: There is already a nurse registered with that id."
  foundError=1 
fi

if [[  -n $centerHasNurse ]]; then
  echo "Error: The Health Center introduced already has a nurse in it."
  foundError=1
fi

if [[ -n $foundError ]]; then
  exit 1
fi

## If we got to this part, there were no errors and we can modify the file
echo "$2:$1:$3:0:$4" >> nurses.txt
echo "Nurse added."
```

Answer (score 2):

As others have pointed out, `grep -c "$3"` and `grep -c "$2"` perform a regular expression search, which is not, by default (in `grep`, at least), a full match (i.e. from beginning to end) between a string and a pattern. Also, a regular expression search in place of a test for equality may lead to unwanted results when the pattern (`"$3"` and `"$2"`, in your case) is allowed to include special characters (e.g. `CSPorto01` would match the pattern `CSPorto.1`).

Beside suggesting a solution to that issue, here is an example of how you could take more advantage of AWK's features. Your program is split into the `add_nurses.sh` shell script and the `add_nurses.awk` AWK script.

```bsh
#!/bin/sh

if [ $# -ne 4 ]
then
  printf '%s\n' "Error: Syntax: $0 <id number>:<name>:<associated Health Center>:<number of vaccines done>:<availabiliy>"
  exit 1
fi

awk -v FS=':' -v OFS=':' -v name="$1" -v id="$2" -v center="$3" -v av="$4" \
  -f add_nurses.awk nurses.txt
```

```c
#!/bin/awk

$3 == center {
  print "Error: The Health Center introduced already has a nurse in it."
  err++
}
$1 == id {
  print "Error: There is already a nurse registered with that id."
  err++
}
END {
  if (! err) {
    print id,name,center,"0",av >>FILENAME
    print "Nurse added."
  }
}
```

(I am not taking care of removing empty lines from `nurses.txt`).

Notes:

- A separate AWK script is easier to read and to maintain (but this is likely a matter of personal preference)
- You do not need a regular expression (`[:]`) as `awk`'s field separator
- It makes sense to print all the errors that the input would give, instead of stopping after the first one
- ...but, at the same time, it makes little sense to parse the input when it is clearly malformed (hence the check for the number of arguments in `add_nurses.sh`)
- There is no real need for non-standard shell features in this case: `[[ ... ]]` is replaced by `[ ... ]`; for the same reason, I used `#!/bin/sh`